# Sum to $n$ terms of the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Find the sum to $n$ terms of the given series:

$$0.3+0.33+0.333+0.3333+\cdots$$

My Attempt:
Let 
$$S=0.3+0.33+0.333+0.3333+\cdots \text{ to $n$ terms}$$ 
$$=\frac {3}{10}+\frac {33}{100}+\frac {333}{1000} + \frac {3333}{10000}+\cdots$$
$$=\frac {3}{10} \left[1+\frac {11}{10}+\frac {111}{100}+\frac {1111}{1000}+\cdots \text{ to $n$ terms}\right]$$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: The sum is larger than $0.3+0.3+0.3+...$, which is larger than $0.3\times N$ for any natural number $N$. Use the Archimedean property to show that for every $M$  there is $N$ such that $0.3N>M$ (equivalently $N>M/0.3$).

Comment: Ha! I read tonsofterms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the sum by $3$ and add $0.111\cdots1$ ($n$ decimals). You get $n$, by distributing the ones.

But $0.111\cdots1=\dfrac19-\dfrac{10^{-n}}9$ (the subtrahend cancels the tail).

Hence

$$S=\frac{n-0.111\cdots1}3=\frac{9n-1+10^{-n}}{27}.$$

---

**Without words:**

$$\begin{matrix}3\times&0.3&+0.33&+0.333&+0.3333\\
+&0.1&+0.01&+0.001&+0.0001\\
\hline\\
=&1&+1&+1&+1\end{matrix}$$

and

$$\begin{align}&0.1111111111111111\cdots\\
-&0.0000111111111111\cdots\\\hline
=&0.1111
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Write your sum to $n$ terms as $$S_n=0.3+(0,3+0.03)+(0.3+0.03+0.003)+\ldots +(0.3+0.03+0.003+\ldots 0.000000000003)$$
Now note that you have $n$ terms $0.3$, $n-1$ terms $0.03$, $n-2$ terms $0.003$ and so on, so $$S_n=0.3n+0.03(n-1)+0.003(n-2)+\ldots+3\cdot 10^{-n}(1)\\
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n3\cdot 10^{-i}(n+1-i)$$
and we have lots of questions summing the arithmo-geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$S_n=0.3+0.33+0.333+0.3333+\cdots \text{ to $n$ terms}$$ 
$$=\underbrace{\frac {3}{10}+\frac {33}{100}+\frac {333}{1000} + \frac {3333}{10000}+\cdots}_n$$
$$=3\left(\frac {1}{10}+\frac {11}{100}+\frac {111}{1000} + \frac {1111}{10000}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac {1}{10^1}+\frac {11}{10^2}+\frac {111}{10^3} + \frac {1111}{10^4}+\cdots\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac {\sum_{k=0}^010^k}{10^1}+\frac {\sum_{k=0}^110^k}{10^2}+\frac {\sum_{k=0}^210^k}{10^3} + \frac {\sum_{k=0}^310^k}{10^4}+\cdots+\frac {\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)}10^k}{10^n}\right)$$

And $$\frac{1}{10^{n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right)= \frac{1}{10^{n}}\left(\frac{10^{n}-1}{9}\right) = \frac{1}{9}\left(1 - \frac{1}{10^n}\right) = \frac{1}{9}\left(1 - 10^{-n}\right)$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
S_n &= 3\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{1}{9}\left(1 - 10^{-k}\right)\right]\right)\\
&= \frac{3}{9}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1 - 10^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n10^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left( n- \sum_{k=1}^n10^{-k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left( n- \frac{1}{9}\left(1 - 10^{-n}\right)\right)
\end{align}

> $$S_n = \frac{1}{27}\left(10^{-n}+ 9n -1\right) $$

Comment: You just copy-pasted $$\frac{1}{10^{n}} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k\right) = \frac{1}{9} (1 - 10^{-n})$$ at the third to last row, when computing $$\sum_{k=\bbox[yellow]{1}}^n 10^{-k} = -1 +\sum_{k=\bbox[yellow]{0}}^n 10^{-k} = -1+\frac{10^{-n-1}-1}{9} =\frac{10^{-n-1}-10}{9} =\frac{10}{9} (10^{-n-2}-1).$$

Comment: Please don't simply copy [your answer from an identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2751729).

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for your comment. How should I do in the case? 
I find my answer helpful, but it will be deleted because the question already exists.

Comment: You answered both questions, so you know that they are identical. You could just comment to the duplicate question that it has already been answered. You could even link to your previous answer. However, identical answers without reference to each other can cause confusion (are these answers the same?), represents duplication of effort (in both writing and reading), and might be termed self-plagiarism.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, I'll keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac {3}{10} \left(1+\dfrac {11}{10}+\dfrac {111}{100}+\dfrac {1111}{1000}+\ldots\right) \\
=\dfrac {3}{10} \left(\dfrac{1}{10^0}+\dfrac {10 +1}{10^1}+\dfrac {10^2 +10 +1}{10^2}+\dfrac {10^3+10^2+10+1}{10^3}+\ldots\right)
$$
Each fraction has a (finite) geometric series in the denominator (there is a formula for those) and a power of ten in the denominator.
$$=\frac3{10}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{10^k} \sum_{j=0}^k 10^j .$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate $$A=1+\dfrac {99\div 9}{10}+\dfrac {999\div9}{100}+\dfrac {9999\div 9}{1000}+...+\dfrac{(10^{n}-1)\div9}{10^{n-1}}$$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A&=\frac {3}{10} \left(1+\frac {11}{10}+\frac {111}{100}+\frac {1111}{1000}+\cdots +\frac{(10^{n}-1)\div9}{10^{n-1}}\right) \\
&=1+\dfrac {99\div 9}{10}+\dfrac {999\div9}{100}+\dfrac {9999\div 9}{1000}+\cdots+\dfrac{(10^{n}-1)\div9}{10^{n-1}} \\
&=1+\dfrac{99\times10^{n-2}\div9}{10^{n-1}}+\dfrac{999\times10^{n-3}\div9}{10^{n-1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{(10^{n}-1)\div9}{10^{n-1}} \\
&=1+\dfrac{(10^2-1)\times10^{n-2}+(10^3-1)\times10^{n-3}+(10^4-1)\times10^{n-4}+\cdots+(10^n-1)}{9\times 10^{n-1}} \\
&=1+\dfrac{10^n-10^{n-2}+10^n-10^{n-3}+10^n-10^{n-4}+\cdots+10^n-1}{9\times 10^{n-1}}\text{ ($n-1$ terms)}\\
&=1+\dfrac{(n-1)10^n-(10^0+10^1+10^2+\cdots+10^{n-3}+10^{n-2})}{9\times 10^{n-1}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Continue to calculate

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
B&=10^0+10^1+10^2+\cdots+10^{n-3}+10^{n-2} \\
10B&=10^1+10^2+10^3+\cdots+10^{n-2}+10^{n-1}\\
\Rightarrow9B&=10B-B=10^{n-1}-1\\
 B&=\dfrac{10^{n-1}-1}{9}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

We can conclude that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A&=1+\dfrac{(n-1)10^n-\dfrac{10^{n-1}-1}{9}}{9\times 10^{n-1}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 1):

The recursion $10S_n=S_{n-1}+3n$ with $S_0=0$ implies

$$S_n=a\left(\left(1\over10\right)^n-1\right)+bn$$

for some $a$ and $b$.  From $S_1={3\over10}$ and $S_2={63\over100}$ we have

$$\begin{align}
{3\over10}&=a\left({1\over10}-1\right)+b\\
{63\over100}&=a\left({1\over100}-1\right)+2b
\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}
9a-10b&=-3\\
99a-200b&=-63
\end{align}$$

which solves to $b=1/3$ and $a=1/27$, so

$$S_n={1\over27}\left(\left(1\over10\right)^n-1\right)+{1\over3}n$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's different flavor that's more elementary and explicit (maybe).

At the $k$-th term among summing $k=1$ to $k = n$, we have the multiplicative factor you got:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ 111\cdots11 }{ 100\cdots00} &= 1 + \frac1{10} + \frac1{100} + \cdots \frac1{10^{k-1}} \tag*{, totally $k$ terms}\\
&= \frac{ 1 - (1/10)^k}{1 - 1/10} \\
&= \frac{10}9 \left( 1 - \frac1{10^k}\right)
\end{align*}
Thus the original summation of $n$ terms is
\begin{align*}
S = \frac3{10}\frac{10}9 \sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 - \frac1{10^k}\right) &= \frac13 \cdot \left(n - \frac{ \frac1{10} - \frac1{10^{n+1}} }{1 - \frac1{10}} \right) \\
&=\frac13 \cdot \left(n - \frac19 \left(1 - \frac1{10^n} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac13 \cdot \left(n - \frac19 \frac{ \,\,\overbrace{ 999\cdots 99 }^{n~\text{digits} }}{ \underbrace{ 100\cdots 000 }_{n+1~\text{digits} } } \right) \\
&= \frac13 \left( n -  \frac{ \,\,\overbrace{ 111\cdots 11 }^{n~\text{digits} }}{ \underbrace{ 100\cdots 000 }_{n+1~\text{digits} } }\right) = \frac13 \cdot (n - 0.111\cdots 11)
\end{align*}
There are $n$ digits of $1$ following the decimal point. Or if you prefer,$$S = \frac13 \bigl(n - 1 + 0.888\cdots 89 \bigr)$$where there are $n-1$ digits of $8$ followed by a single $9$.